# whats different between s:FormItem and mx:FormItem in flex4

Tags: apache-flex, web-applications

When i use the the Form and FormItem in flex,I found the s:FormItem can't place its label position automatically and can't use direction, horizentalGap properties, but adobe recommended us to use  spark.components.FormItem instead of mx.containers。FormItem,so can you teel me the different about these two class,and tell me why the properties such as direction, horizentalGap can't use in spark.components.FormItem.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [mx FormItem](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/FormItem.html) is "legacy" code and was built using the [MX / Halo component architecture](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf68641-7ff0.html).

The [Spark FormItem](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/FormItem.html) was built using the new [Spark component architecture](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html).  The Flex Framework Components built in each respective architecture are not identical.

If you want to specify a "Direction" in the Spark FormItem you could try setting it's [layout property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnableContainer.html#layout) to either a [horizontal or vertical layout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS0141D24B-6AEB-4721-BA04-9BF15F86350F.html).